# Output only active

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make this IP scanner only show the active IPs that it pings any help be awesome.
thank you.

```
# Script to ping all IP addresses in a /24 subnet
import os

network = input ("Enter IP Network to scan: ")
print(network)

# Iterate over all usable IPs in this subnet
for host in range (1, 254):
 print("Pinging " + network + "." + str(host))
 os.system("ping -c 2 " + network + "." + str(host))
```

Comment: What did you try? Did you consider reading the output of the command you are executing?

Comment: i am still learning python atm but the output i am getting is. --- 192.168.0.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1009ms
pipe 2
Pinging 192.168.0.3
PING 192.168.0.3 (192.168.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.12 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.12 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable   but i just want it to show the successful ones

Comment: You have to check the return os.system call and to print only those IP addresses for which result is equal 0 or 2.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg How would i do that would i do it with a if loop or a while loop and then how would i write it as said before still learning and having a mind block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you do not to analyze output of ping command but its exit code. According to man page

```
 The ping utility exits with one of the following values:
 0       At least one response was heard from the specified host.
 2       The transmission was successful but no responses were received.
 any other value An error occurred.
```

So the code might be like this.

```
import os

network = input ("Enter IP Network to scan: ")
print(network)

for host in range (1, 254):
   print("Pinging " + network + "." + str(host))
   h = network + "." + str(host)
   res = os.system("ping -q -c 2 " + h)
   if res == 1 or res == 2: 
       print("host " + h + "is active"
```

Answer (score 0):

On pinging the IP, you get some results in some string format. Try thinking about how different IPs produce different results. For example, for an active IP address, this is how the string might look like-

```
PING 10.0.0.254 (10.0.0.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.254: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms

--- 10.0.0.254 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1021ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.030/0.037/0.044/0.007 ms
```

And for an inactive one,

```
PING 10.0.0.253 (10.0.0.253) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.254 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.254 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 10.0.0.253 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1015ms
pipe 2
```

So think about how you can parse these string objects to decide? One very simple example that one can observe is,

```py
if 'Unreachable' not in output:
    print(ip + ' is active')
```

You can also look at ping statistics and retrieve the packet loss. If it's 100%, the network is down! Look at how you can play around with strings, how you can split based on tokens, or find substrings. You can also use regular expressions if you are feeling naughty.

Comment: thanks for the info it has been very helpfully and given me some more knowledge i thank you